# Loop through a split string variable to insert rows in a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am working on SQL Server 2008 to create a stored procedure that:

1. takes a string variable like this: `'1,2,3'`
2. splits the string using a table-valued function to get each value separately
3. and then inserts each value into a new row in a table

What I am trying to do is something like this:

```
WHILE (select vlaue FROM dbo.SplitString('1,2,3',',')) has rows
insert into TableName (col1,col2) values (col1Data, value)
```

I am having a hard time trying to find the right syntax for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` should do:

```
INSERT INTO TableName (col1,col2)
SELECT @col1Data,value FROM dbo.SplitString('1,2,3',','))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. check the comments in the first answer please

Comment: @Alsmayer Updated for an extra column being a parameter from the SP.

Answer (score 9):

I use this Table-valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (@sep char(1), @s varchar(512))
 RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
  SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
  FROM Pieces
  WHERE stop > 0
)
SELECT pn,
  SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
FROM Pieces
)
GO
```

Which takes a string with a separator and returns a table with two columns the first returns a 1-based position and the second the element at that position in the string:

Usage:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(',', '1,2,3')
```

Returns:

```
pn  s
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

To Insert results into a table:

```
INSERT INTO TableName (Col1)
SELECT S FROM dbo.Split(',', '1,2,3)
```

For your specific example change your syntax to be:

```
   insert into TableName (col1,col2) 
   select col1Data, value FROM dbo.SplitString('1,2,3',',')
```

Comment: I don't have a problem with the split function. it works fine with me

Comment: what I need is a way to insert each value in the split string in a new row in a table. thanks

Answer (score 4):

If someone else is looking for this, I was about to make a split function as several answers mentioned but noticed there's a built-in function that does this already.

string_split was added in MSSQL 2016.

```
INSERT INTO Project.FormDropdownAnswers (FkTableId, CreatedBy, CreatedDate)
SELECT 123, TRY_CAST(value AS INT), @username, getdate() 
FROM string_split('44,45,46,47,55',',')
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE tablename
(
    id SMALLINT ,
    value INT
)

 INSERT INTO tablename ( id, value )
 SELECT * FROM dbo.Split('1,2,3',',')
```

try this....

Answer (score 0):

If need to use as variables there is 2 nice options:

Procedure MF_SPLIT

```
CREATE PROC [MF_SPLIT] (@ELS NVARCHAR(MAX)=NULL OUTPUT, @RET NVARCHAR(MAX)=NULL OUTPUT, @PROC NVARCHAR(MAX)=NULL) AS BEGIN
    
    IF @ELS IS NULL BEGIN
PRINT ' @ELS
 
List of elements in string (OUTPUT)
 
    @RET
    
Next return (OUTPUT)
 
    @PROC
    
NULL = '','', content to do split
 
    Example:
 
DECLARE @NAMES VARCHAR(100) = ''ERICK,DE,VATHAIRE''
DECLARE @N VARCHAR(100)
WHILE @NAMES IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    EXEC MF_SPLIT @NAMES OUTPUT, @N OUTPUT
    SELECT List = @NAMES, ActiveWord = @N
END'
        RETURN
    END
 
    SET @PROC = ISNULL(@PROC, ',')
    IF CHARINDEX(@PROC, @ELS) = 0 BEGIN
        SELECT @RET = @ELS, @ELS = NULL
        RETURN
    END
    SELECT
        @RET = LEFT(@ELS, CHARINDEX(@PROC, @ELS) - 1)
        , @ELS = STUFF(@ELS, 1, LEN(@RET) + 1, '')
END
```

Usage:

```
DECLARE @NAMES VARCHAR(100) = '1,2,3'
DECLARE @N VARCHAR(100)
WHILE @NAMES IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    EXEC MF_SPLIT @NAMES OUTPUT, @N OUTPUT
    SELECT List = @NAMES, ActiveWord = @N
END
```

Procedure MF_SPLIT_DO (Depends of MF_SPLIT), less sintax to use BUT the code will be in a string and use default variable "@X"

```
CREATE PROC MF_SPLIT_DO (@ARR NVARCHAR(MAX), @DO NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS BEGIN
        --Less sintax
    DECLARE @X NVARCHAR(MAX)
    WHILE @ARR IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        EXEC MF_SPLIT @ARR OUT, @X OUT
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @DO, N'@X NVARCHAR(MAX)', @X
    END
END
```

Usage:

```
EXEC MF_SPLIT_DO '1,2,3', 'SELECT @X'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL Server 2016 or above and the compatibility level is 130 or above you can use the **STRING_SPLIT** table-valued function

```
INSERT INTO tableName (col1, col2)
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.STRING_SPLIT('ANY TEXT', ' ', 1);
```

The output includes an ordinal when the optional parameter '1' is included

```
-- view compatibility level
SELECT compatibility_level  
FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'tableName';  
GO 

-- update compatibility level
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName  
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 150;  
GO
```

Reference:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database?view=sql-server-ver16